# Samba 4 ADDC with Bind_DLZ in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bind, active-directory, samba4

Is there a tutorial around that I'm missing on how to set up Bind 9.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 for integration with Samba4 ADDC? The official Samba Wiki only covers Bind 9.8 and Bind 9.9 setup. I'm at a dead-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this article (http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/samba4-ad-dc-on-ubuntu-14-04/) is titled referencing U14.04, I have successfully used it with U16.04.1LTS. Surprisingly, this article is quite close to being correct, there are just a few pieces of the puzzle missing.

First, ext4, there is no need to manually adjust the acl and attr in /etc/fstab settings. By default, ext4 now handles all that. (Read the Samba Wiki to confirm.) So, just ignore that acl section of the article. But, do install acl and attr.

The other pieces that are missing are setting the correct nameserver, configuring krb5-user, installing winbind and (chuckle) installing bind9 (I cannot get over the fact that you cannot configure bind9 if you have not installed it yet but, like I said the article is close to correct.) The nameserver, winbind, and krb5-user settings can be found in the samba wiki.

(added later, see I forgot this) You need to provision per the article but add --use-ntvfs to the end of your provision options. (Sorry, did not note why.)

I hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference in syntax between versions? Is there major config file changes? I would suspect not between minor upgrades like 9.9 to 9.10 according to the [bind website](https://www.isc.org/bind-9-10-new-features/) it would appear not. They seem to have only added more tools and improved performance!

So you should be fine to follow an installation guide for a previous version with all the added benefits of the latest version!

Of course there may be a few bugs or some of the techniques from the instructions may be out of date, but you can always ask here or do some googling!

Comment: Yeah, true. this is all part of a much larger project, and I'm getting myself confused recently... I have since taken a step back, and reassessed the requirements of the project. Still looking to use the BIND tutorial that I found for the project I am planning. Thanks for the answer, and general reassurance.